# min/max number by group, with recurring group criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

I'm trying to create an address directory where

- for each street_key
- there is one row containing the address_no_start and address_no_end
- until a change happens in the region variables

The problem occurs when a street_key re-enters to its previous region leading to wrong results using a very basic "group by/min-max" approach

The results show 2 rows with start 1 and end 13 becuase the street returns to REGION1 003 after with ADRESS_NO 11

```
DECLARE @adressInRegion AS TABLE (
ADRESS_KEY CHAR(5),
ADRESS_NO INT,
REGION1 CHAR(3),
REGION2 CHAR(2),
REGION3 CHAR(5),
REGION4 CHAR(2)
)


INSERT INTO @adressInRegion 
VALUES
('12345',1,'003','02','55555','12'),
('12345',3,'003','02','55555','12'),
('12345',5,'003','02','55555','12'),
('12345',7,'005','02','55555','12'),
('12345',9,'005','02','55555','12'),
('12345',11,'003','02','55555','12'),
('12345',13,'003','02','55555','12')


SELECT 
  ADRESS_KEY, 
  MIN(ADRESS_NO) AS ADRESS_NO_START,
  MAX(ADRESS_NO) AS ADRESS_NO_END,
  REGION1,
  REGION2,
  REGION3,
  REGION4
FROM @adressInRegion
GROUP BY
  ADRESS_KEY, 
  REGION1,
  REGION2,
  REGION3,
  REGION4
```

outcome:

[image]

Desired outcome:
[image]

Comment: What is your question here, exactly? You start off by telling us what you're doing, and that sometimes it doesn't work, but then you just give us sample data and (presumably) your attempt. You don't explain why what you have isn't working, nor what the results you want are.

Comment: Why are you explicitly casting `ADRESS_NO` to an `int` in your `SELECT` when it's already defined as `ADRESS_NO INT [NULL]`? Converting an `int` to an `int` achieves nothing.

Comment: I thought that "The problem occurs when a street_key re-enters to its previous region leading to wrong results using a very basic "group by/min-max" approach" describes the problem.

The street leaves REGION1 003 and enters REGION1 005 after ADRESS_NO 5. This should be one result row with ADRESS_NO_START 1 and ADRESS_NOEND 5.

Afterwards there should be one row for REGION1 005 with start 7 and end 9 and a third row for REGION1 003 start 11, end 13

Because REGION1 003 is the same for both ADRESS_NO 1-5 and 11-13 the result contians only 2 rows with REGION1 003 1-13 and 005 5-9

Comment: *"The problem occurs"* *What* problem...? "My car has a problem when I'm driving it." Can you diagnose and fix a car on that statement alone? No, and neither can we on yours. You need to *explain* in detail. Show your expected results for the data you have. You talk about, in the above, that the value of a column has changed, so demonstrate that `UPDATE` occuring and why the *new* result set (by running the same SQL) is then wrong, and what you instead expect.

Comment: I have *assumed* you are using SQL Server here, based on the [[tag:tsql]] tag. If you are using a different product that uses T-SQL, such as Azure Synapse, Sybase, Azure SQL Edge, etc, then please [edit] your tags to correct the tag(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a little trick, numbering you rows according to you group key, and adding it to a descending row number.

```
SELECT
        ADRESS_KEY
       ,ADRESS_NO
       ,REGION1
       ,REGION2
       ,REGION3
       ,REGION4
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ADRESS_KEY, REGION1, REGION2, REGION4, REGION4 ORDER BY ADRESS_NO) +
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ADRESS_KEY ORDER BY ADRESS_NO DESC) grp
    FROM @adressInRegion
```

This gives you

```
+------------+-----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----+
| ADRESS_KEY | ADRESS_NO | REGION1 | REGION2 | REGION3 | REGION4 | grp |
+------------+-----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----+
|      12345 |         1 |     003 |      02 |   55555 |      12 |   8 |
|      12345 |         3 |     003 |      02 |   55555 |      12 |   8 |
|      12345 |         5 |     003 |      02 |   55555 |      12 |   8 |
|      12345 |         7 |     005 |      02 |   55555 |      12 |   5 |
|      12345 |         9 |     005 |      02 |   55555 |      12 |   5 |
|      12345 |        11 |     003 |      02 |   55555 |      12 |   6 |
|      12345 |        13 |     003 |      02 |   55555 |      12 |   6 |
+------------+-----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----+
```

Now you can do max min on each group. Here it's done via a CTE:

```
;WITH cte
AS
(SELECT
        ADRESS_KEY
       ,ADRESS_NO
       ,REGION1
       ,REGION2
       ,REGION3
       ,REGION4
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ADRESS_KEY, REGION1, REGION2, REGION4, REGION4 ORDER BY ADRESS_NO) +
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ADRESS_KEY ORDER BY ADRESS_NO DESC) grp
    FROM @adressInRegion)
SELECT
    ADRESS_KEY
   ,MIN(ADRESS_NO) ADRESS_NO_START
   ,MAX(ADRESS_NO) ADRESS_NO_END
   ,REGION1
   ,REGION2
   ,REGION3
   ,REGION4
FROM cte
GROUP BY ADRESS_KEY
        ,REGION1
        ,REGION2
        ,REGION3
        ,REGION4
        ,grp
ORDER BY ADRESS_KEY,ADRESS_NO_START
```

Result:

```
+------------+-----------------+---------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| ADRESS_KEY | ADRESS_NO_START | ADRESS_NO_END | REGION1 | REGION2 | REGION3 | REGION4 |
+------------+-----------------+---------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|      12345 |               1 |             5 |     003 |      02 |   55555 |      12 |
|      12345 |               7 |             9 |     005 |      02 |   55555 |      12 |
|      12345 |              11 |            13 |     003 |      02 |   55555 |      12 |
+------------+-----------------+---------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```